# $3$D analog to the catenary

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, physics

**Introduction**: Given a plane $(2d)$, two points $(0d)$, and a curve $("1d")$ analogous to a chain (constant length, points can only rotate around their neighbouring points and cant distance or approach themselves to their neighbouring points, and it is non-self intersecting) hanging from the points, under an uniform gravitational field, we have a catenary.

**Question**: Given the space $(3d)$, two curves $(1d)$, and a surface $(2d)$ (with analogous characteristics, e.g. if the lenght of the chain was fixed before, now the area of the surface is fixed), we have a... what? What is its name?

[**Answer**: In civil engineering this surface is called "*catenary membranes*" or "*catenary domes*"]

**Clarification**: Illustration of the surface: Imagine I have a pair of curves with finite length, a mesh of inelastic strings (making tiny rectangular cells, for example), and the mesh is hanging from the curves under a uniform gravitational field

A **source** for physics of the differential equation that leads to the catenary: Exercise **9** on **p. 9** of *Professor Shiffrin's* **DIFFERENTIAL GEOMETRY: A First Course in Curves and Surfaces**

Another **source**: https://parametricmonkey.com/2015/10/10/catenary-curves/

Comment: Are we supposed to imagine the 2d surface as a piece of cloth, where the area and intrinsic curvature are both fixed, or a liquid mosaic, where the area is fixed but the curvature can vary or as something else?

Comment: Area is fixed and it is not something other than a piece of cloth or liquid mosaic. I have no familiarity with the concept of intrinsic curvature. I would suppose I am reffering to the case of fixed intrinsic curvature, since, to use a mechanical analogy, one could naively think that cloth would be the 2d analog of a string. But you got me curious about both cases. Thanks for the comment. I am new here, how should I edit my question to make it clearer?

Comment: I have no idea what you're thinking of. The ingredient you've left out of the 2D situation in your discussion of the catenary is *gravity*.  I don't know what you're thinking of in 3D, but there needs to be gravity in that question as well.

Comment: Have you thought about the physics of the differential equation that leads to the catenary? (A source with which I'm familiar is Exercise 9 on p. 9 of my differential geometry text, linked in my profile.) What is the analogue for your case? This isn't clear to me. You might start by working with a parametrization of the surface in question.

Comment: @RickyTensor Added edits pitched by you. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: I think you should answer your own question. @TedShifrin may not want to spend time doing so.

Comment: You have the wrong reference for the catenary exercise. Wrong book. I still do not understand the construction you have in mind for the surface. I don't know how we've arrived at an "answer" here.

Comment: Sorry, corrected the reference

Comment: The name of the surface in civil engineering is "_catenary membrane_" or "_catenary dome_" Knowing its name and that it is all about differential geometry and physics, and having a textbook and lectures for half of it, is already a pretty good starting point.